# I used regex to get specific data in file and I want to add characters after those data

Tags: python, regex

I used regex to get specific data in file and I want to add characters after those data

Here is my code:

```
import re
import os
All =[]
for fil in os.listdir('Input/'):
    with open('Input/' + fil , encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as files:
        text = file = files.read()
        #print(re.search('Play_(.*?)refParamName', str(file)))
        find = re.findall('Play_(.*?)refParamName', text)
        print(find)
```

Here is the returned result:

```
[]
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Attack" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Short" ']
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Attack_Hit" ']
['DiaoChan_Attack" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Short" ']
['DiaoChan_Attack" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Anger" ']
[]
['DiaoChan_VO_Dead" ']
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_D_Hit" ']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_D_Hit" ']
['DiaoChan_Skill_D_Hit" ']
['DiaoChan_Skill_A" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Skill_A" ']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_A_Hit" ']
['DiaoChan_Skill_A_Hit" ']
['DiaoChan_Skill_B" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Skill_B" ']
[]
[]
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_B_Hit" ', 'DiaoChan_Skill_E_Hit" ']
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_C" ', 'DiaoChan_VO_Skill_C" ']
[]
[]
['DiaoChan_Skill_C_Hit" ']
[]
```

I want to add after it characters like this:
'DiaoChan_Attack_Skin6"

'DiaoChan_VO_Short_Skin6"

'DiaoChan_Attack_Hit_Skin6"

'DiaoChan_Attack_Skin6"

'DiaoChan_VO_Short_Skin6"

'DiaoChan_Attack_Skin6"

I need help and Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the changes in files I'd suggest to use re.sub instead of re.findall

```py
new_text = re.sub('Play_(.*?)refParamName','Play_\\1{}refParamName'.format('_Skin6'), text)
with open('Output/{}'.format(fil)) as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

But if you just want to add the changes to the result of the re.findall, then

```
find = re.findall('Play_(.*?)refParamName', text)
All.append([match + '_Skin6' for match in find])
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work Here is my code after change:https://anotepad.com/notes/6i588p8x

Comment: Because you badly indented the code, you have to write every time when you calculate the new_text

Comment: Thank you very much Bro. I realized my mistake and completed the project

 . Once again Thank you very much Bro